# I have problem with my multiplication table,

Tags: c

So i have problem with multiplication by 0.[closed]
This is my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int i,c,x,b,q,w,e,r,t,y,u;

    for (i = 1; i <=11; i++) {
        printf("0 * %-2d = %-2d\n", i - 1, x=0), x = x * 0;
    }
    for (i = 1; i <= 11; i++)
    {
        printf("1 * %-2d = %-2d\n",i-1,x),x= 1 * i;
    }
    for (i = 1; i <= 11; i++)
    {
        printf("2 * %-2d = %-2d\n",i-1,b),b= 2 * i;
    }
    for (i = 1; i <= 11; i++)
    {
        printf("3 * %-2d = %-2d\n",i-1,c),c= 3 * i;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= 11; i++)
    {
        printf("4 * %-2d = %-2d\n",i-1,q),q= 4 *i;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= 11; i++)
    {
        printf("5 * %-2d = %-2d\n",i-1,w),w= 5 *i;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= 11; i++)
    {
        printf("6 * %-2d = %-2d\n",i-1,e),e= 6 *i;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= 11; i++)
    {
        printf("7 * %-2d = %-2d\n",i-1,r),r= 7 *i;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= 11; i++)
    {
        printf("8 * %-2d = %-2d\n",i-1,t),t= 8 *i;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= 11; i++)
    {
        printf("9 * %-2d = %-2d\n",i-1,y),y= 9 *i;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= 11; i++)
    {
        printf("10 * %-2d = %-2d\n",i-1,u),u= 10 *i;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And i have problem with output by 0

- 10 * 0  = 32599
- 10 * 1  = 10
- 10 * 2  = 20
- All good with multiplication by 1,2,3... but with zero i have problem and don't know what to do

Comment: `printf("10 * %-2d = %-2d\n",i-1,u),u= 10 *i;` Most of your variables are not correctly initialised. `u` contains garbage on the first iteration.

Comment: Ok, and what should i do?

Comment: `u=10` at the top or before the `for` loop. That is, initialise it before using it.

Comment: Aside: When you find yourself having to repeat the same code over and over again it is an indication that the code structure is wrong. You can shorten this code significantly by using a nested `for` loop.

Comment: Can u show how should i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding @kaylum's comment about using a nested for loop, it looks like you're really just looking for something like this...

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  for (int x = 0; x <= 10; x++) {
    for (int y = 1; y <= 10; y++) {
      printf("%-2d * %-2d = %-2d\n", x, y, x * y);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```